# Need to geocode in Arcmap using only city, state

Tags: arcgis, geocode, arcmap

Using ArcMap 10.x's geocode address feature, I would like to ommit 'address' and have it only use CITY and STATE to return lat/long values. How do I do this?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not familiar with ARCGIS, but I know you can get lat/lon from City and State with the [SmartyStreets ZIP API](https://smartystreets.com/docs/city-state-zip). Try out their [demo](https://smartystreets.com/demo?city=New+York&state=ny).

Comment: You may not be aware but there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange with MANY ArcGIS for Desktop questions already answered.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcCatalog, right-click and choose New > Address Locator.

In the Address Locator dialog box, choose either "***General - City State Country***" or choose "***US Address - City State***".

Read up on ArcGIS address locator basics here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/creating-an-address-locator.htm